# Swagger: Change example in model class

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Asumming a model class with swagger annotation like this:

```
class Car {

    @Schema(name = "Brand of car", example = "Tesla")
    public String brand;

    @Schema(name = "Color of car", example = "red")
    public String color;
}
```

Now I have two endpoints in the controller like this:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok", content = 
      { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = 
        @Schema(implementation = Car.class)) })
public Car getRedCar() {...}

@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok", content = 
      { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = 
        @Schema(implementation = Car.class)) })
public Car getBlueCar() {...}
```

With my current example in the `car`, the first endpoint is well documented, but the second endpoint looks very wrong. Swagger displays the JSON response in both cases with the example color "red".

A solution would be to not reference the `Car.class` and manually define JSON as String in the endpoint. However, if I add or remove an attribute from `Car`, the swagger documentaion will not get updated automatically.

So, how can I customize the model example based on the endpoint without manually defining the example by hand?

Comment: can you explain more, what exactly does 'looks very wrong' mean?

Comment: I edit an explanation.

Comment: How about inheritance? Like: Class BlueCar extends Car. Class RedCar extends Car.